# Why can TV broadcasts send such large amounts of data(photorealism) and a PC can't

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, photons

Firstly I think I am right in saying that TV broadcast are sent via electromagnetic waves which means they are sent via photons, how is that even possible?

And then the main questions, how can you broadcast such large amounts of data over the airwaves and produce photorealistic TV and a PC cannot.

I understand a bit about offline and real-time rendering, and I guess it's that for a PC game you have to interact which using a lot more processing power. So how does TV do it, will PC games ever get to photorealistic levels?

Answer (score 4):

PCs surely can send (via Wi-Fi or another connection) the information to reproduce much better-quality video than the ordinary classical analog television.

Analog television is receiving 50 pictures a second. Each of them has 625 rows of 625 pixels, roughly speaking. That's about 20 million pixels per second that are caught by a TV (from one channel). Each pixel may be transmitted with the accuracy of 3 bytes or so we may need something like 60 million bytes per second to transmit the classical TV in a great quality and without compression.

That corresponds to something like 480 Mbits per second, a very good internet connection that some people have. In the analog world, most of the required information may be transmitted by electromagnetic waves in VHF and UHF (from 50 to 1,000 MHz, one MHz is one million periods of the sine wave per second). However, most of the information on the TV screen is redundant and compressed video may – without any loss of quality that would be clear to the human eye – reduce the required transfer of information dramatically. So 1 Mbit per second (480 times less than in the example above) is already enough to transfer photorealistic, great quality moving images via the Internet.

After all, TV broadcasting has largely switched from analog to digital – so it works like computers – and the modern TV sets are intrinsically digital, too. They have much higher quality than the older analog models of TVs. High-definition TV and sometimes ultrahigh-definition TV is expanding; the latter's resolution is almost 10 times (in each dimension) better than the classical TV.

A completely different question is whether computers may simulate the real world so that it looks genuine. They got really far. Even 4 years ago, ordinary PC games like Mafia II were pretty realistic, see e.g.

> http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JTKQYXezOeo&list=PL300EF774D60038B9

But the analog television isn't simulating the world. It's just transmitting the information that was captured by an analog camcorder in the real world. You can't compare the ability to simulate ("produce") an artificial world with the abilities of devices to simply take pictures of objects in the real world, transmit them, and display them again! To confuse these two activities would be equally foolish as to confuse the production of a Mercedes car and driving one.

Comment: I would just add/enhance the fact that analog tv broadcast has such a high bandwidth because is the same information for all users (and without working reciprocally) in contrast with internet.

Comment: Well, nice, but it doesn't! VHF television starts at 50 MHz and the number of bits per second in an analog TV signal is never greater than the frequency times 20 (sometimes just 2!) - which makes at most 1 Gbit per second (and it's usually much less). Some people already have a thicker internet connection than that even though it is "personal" and goes in both directions (the latter fact just means that we need a factor of two in the total transferred information in both ways, not a big deal).

Comment: And with the video compression, even average people's Internet connections are surely capable to transfer a higher-quality signal than the classical TV analog signal.

Comment: @cinico standard definition TV is less than 4Mb/s.  Serious HD might be 10x that.

Comment: @tfb I'm not sure if I agree. If you are talking about digital TV, that's ok. But I was referring to analog transmission, and in that case I do not agree with the 4 Mb/s for data transfer rate.

Comment: @cinico TV has been processed digitally for a long time (long before it was transmitted digitally):  DV tape was something like 25Mbit/s but this was much nicer than would generally be transmitted.  There is no analogue magic which makes the bandwidth be enormously high.

Comment: @tfb Ok. I don't disagree, but I believe that now I understand your comment (I was not understanding where the disagreement was). When I said in my first comment the analog TV had such a large bandwidth, I was not emphasizing the **need** for that but that it's something that **we can "afford" to have** since it's unidirectional.

Comment: @cinico You only sort-of can afford lots of bandwidth: in practice you can't because spectrum is a scarce resource.  One of the tragedies of broadcast digital TV is that (at least in the UK) rather than making use of much better compression to transmit rather more, much higher quality channels, they elected to transmit hugely more channels which were of visibly lower quality than the analogue channels (by 'quality' I mean 'picture quality').  The internet is now fixing the picture-quality problem.

Comment: @tfb Yeah, I know